# Making x the subject of the formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to do this for an hour, with no success. The objective is to make x the subject of this formula.

$$4^{ax} = b \cdot 8^x$$.

I've tried converting everything into a power of 2, but have no idea what to do with the b to get an answer:

$$2^{2ax} = b \cdot 2^{3x}$$

Comment: Do you mean $4^{ax}$ or $4^{a}x$ ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Try taking the logarithm (base $2$) of both sides.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I mean the former

Comment: @MichaelBurr thank you, but I have no idea how to use log :( can I do it without?

Comment: No, the answer involves $\log_2b$, so you need logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

I start from $2^{2ax} = b \cdot 2^{3x}$

$b$ is necessarily positive. Let's say $b=4$

Now $4=2^2$ and the problem can be solved easily

$2^{2ax}=2^2\cdot 2^{3x}$ and then $2^{2ax}=2^{2+3x}$ from which $x=\dfrac{2}{2 a-3}$

If $b=8$ we can do a similar thing and get $x=\dfrac{3}{2 a-3}$

If $b=2^n$ the result is $x=\dfrac{n}{2 a-3}$

This is the simplest way to explain the solution without *logarithm*

*Logarithms* are necessary if $b$ is not a perfect power of $2$

Hope this helps

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!!!!

Comment: @WildPoppy If you like my answer you can click top left where you see the arrows and give me points :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
4^{ax} &=& b \times 8^x \\
2^{2ax} &=& b \times 2^{3x} \\
2^{2ax-3x} &=& b \\
2^{(2a-3)x} &=& b \\
(2a-3)x &=& \log_2b \\
x &=& \dfrac1{2a-3}\log_2b
\end{array}$$

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but I have no idea how to use log as we have not done that in our class yet... is there a way to do it without? thank you once again for taking the time to help me out

Comment: @WildPoppy No, there is no way to do it without $\log$.

Comment: Okay, I wonder why I was given the question if I wasn't able to do it then, lol. My teacher must've made a mistake. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

take log base two of the equation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
4^{ax}=b 8^{x} \\
2ax = 3x+\log_2 b \\
x= \frac{\log_2 b}{2a-3}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to help :)

Answer (score 0):

$4^{ax} = b \cdot 8^x$

$4^{ax} = 2^{\log_2 b} \cdot 8^x$

$4^{ax} = 2^{\log_2 b} \cdot 2^{3x}$

$2^{2ax} = 2^{\log_2 b} \cdot 2^{3x}$

$2^{2ax} = 2^{\log_2 b+3x}$

Therefore,

$2ax = \log_2 b+3x$

$(2a-3)x = \log_2 b$

And,

$x = \frac {\log_2 b}{2a-3}$